# highcharts web chart inside a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I want to display highcharts web chart on a part bootstrap modal also I want to have a dynamic size along with the bootstrap modal.

What I tried so far is:

**HTML code:**

```
<td><a href="#">${ studentInfo.name }</a></td>
```

**Modal:**

```
<div class="container">
     <div id="studentProfile" class="modal container hide fade in" tabindex="-1">
     ...
     <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="row-fluid">
              <div class="span6">...</div>
              <div class="span6">
                  // chart
                  <div class="span6">
                      <div class="span6">
                      <div id="chart-web" class="span6"></div>
                      </div>
                  </div>

              </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**JS code:**

```
$( function() {

    var $modal = $('#studentProfile');

    $('.profiler').on( 'click', function() {
         $.post('../admin/student_stats.do', 
                 { name : $(this).text() }, function( data ) {

                     console.log( data );
                     console.log( data['studentBean'].myName );
                     $modal.modal();

                 },'json')

            .fail( function () {
                bootbox.alert('Internal Error, please try again.');
            });
    });
});
```

**The chart code:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#chart-web').highcharts({
          ...
    });
});
```

**Result:**
At initial draw it works perfectly fine but

[image]

when I resize the browser

[image]

It messes up the chart. Also when I maximize again the browser the chart still remain like the image shown below. Is there a way to fix this?

If my question isn't clear please kindly comment and I will reply accordingly.

**Update:** Here a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28FEv/3/)

Comment: works fine for me on chrome. which browser are you using

Comment: Chrome also. Try to resize the fiddle so you can see the bug.

Comment: Yea..I did resize..works fine for me..version 31.0 - windows

Comment: @Ani how come its working in your screen while on mine it isn't. Did you resize in to the smallest and to the biggest it can?

Comment: I advice to take care about your classes structure, becuase you have many divs with span6 class, including chart which has also this class. In case when each of them has almost 50% widht, it can be a cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have too many nested `class="span6"` you need to reduce them

```
<!-- Right side -->
<div class="span6">
    <!-- Graphical view of weakness -->
    <div id="chart-web"></div>
</div>
```

change your problem codes to the above codes

<kbd>[Updated Demo click here](http://jsfiddle.net/abbasmhd/28FEv/4/)</kbd>

Comment: I tried this one. In the fiddle it works perfectly fine but in my real app i don't know why the result is different? look at [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e310z7my3w8pf83/Screenshot%202013-12-28%2008.42.28.png)

Comment: it looks like a css issue check for margin and paddin